# How to change Live Paint Objects stroke color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke, fill

I'm trying to change the opacity of an enclosed stroke (path) to 60%, but I can't. Every time I left-click on the enclosed stroke and set the opacity to 60%, that's applied to the fill only (image below):
[image]

Then, when I open the Appearance Window, there's no stroke appearing:
[image]

If I left-click on other strokes, such as the one in the below image, the stroke appears in the Appearance window. So I can change the opacity of this stroke (image):
[image]

But it is impossible to do so to the stroke of the enclosed path above. Left-clicking on its path/stroke/anchor pint, its fill always appears rather than its stroke. So what can I do to change the opacity of the enclosed stroke ? Thanks.

PS: With the strokes that are possible to change their opacity, it seems that I used Live paint Bucket to create Live Paint groups and then colored the areas that these strokes encompass. Then I clicked expand and ungroup these strokes. That allows me to distinguish between strokes and fills of these areas. But for the areas that I did not create Live Paint group and expanded and ungrouped, it seems that I can't distinguish between stroke and fill to change their opacity separately. What could I do?

Comment: In the Appearance panel, click on the ">" arrow beside the word Stroke, so you can see the stroke opacity.

Comment: Thanks. But when I changed the opacity of the stroke in the Appearance window to 0%, the color of the stroke doesn't change (image): https://kek.gg/i/5Cv5b2.png , it remains black.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - [see screen capture here](https://imgur.com/a/QKrFyoV). This suggests something else is happening which you haven't mentioned.  By the way, why is the shape in a goup?

Comment: Thanks. The shape is in a group because I used Live paint Bucket to color it together with some other shapes, and then expanded them.

Comment: @Zhetududf - that might be the issue. There might be another shape in the group with a stroke.

Comment: After expanding them, I also ungrouped them so that I could change their transparency separately. But now I've got a problem with the transparency of the stroke and the fill of each shape. As User ''Danielillo''wrote in the answer below, I shouldn't have messed up a Live Paint object.

Comment: Yes. If you expanded, then the stroke you think you are seeing mightl no longer be an actual stroke, but a filled path.  You could try selecting it by clicking on it, then you may be able to target it to change the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Let see, as far as I see what do you want to get is a black stroke with less opacity. This means a gray stroke.

Changing the stroke opacity you will get unexpected results when just a part of the stroke leave a part of the fill visible, like showed at the gif below.

Why you insist with the opacity instead of changing the stroke ink percentage?

[image: ink percentage]

**Differences between Regular Shape and a LivePaint Object:**

- **Color Panel**: allow changing stroke and fill color
- **Appearance Panel**: allow stroke and fill color changes to *Regular Shapes* but not to *LivePaint Objects*.

  [image: livepaint01]
- Expanding the *LivePaint Object*, no posible color changes at the Color Panel or Appearance Panel

[image]

- The *Expanded Live Paint Object* is a group, to allow color changes individually it is necessary to **Ungroup** the expanded shape.

[image: live paint 02]

Comment: Thanks for your advise. In case that I want to make the stroke disappear by changing its ink percentage to 0%, it seems that the stroke only turns into a very gray color. How to make the stroke disappear when needed? Thanks.

Comment: Apply stroke color = none

Comment: After applying stroke color = none to the aforementioned stroke above, the internal half of the stroke turned into dark-pink and the external half of the stroke remained black as in this image: https://kek.gg/i/43-JWq.png ,      This is the screenshot of the stroke and its fill when the ink percentage is 100% https://kek.gg/i/6GHgw9.png , and this is the screenshot of the stroke and its fill when the ink percentage is 0% https://kek.gg/i/5CW3tz.png

Comment: You are doing a mess with the LivePaint object, I will update the answer

Comment: My recommendation for future graphics like that, don's use Live Paint, just select shapes and change their colors